# Is there a word that means news or delivering news or searching for news that starts with "s"?

Tags: meaning, speech, synonyms

I am looking for a word that means news or related to news that starts with "s".

Are there such words?

Thanks.

Comment: 'searching' begins with s, so the trivial answer is yes ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because arbitrary constraints on word choice are unacceptable on ELU.

Comment: how many letters? any other clues?

Answer (score 3):

Scoop,e.g. "the reporter got the scoop on the scandal", meaning he/she got the story first.